# MongoDB Compare Two Array Values at Particular Index

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection of documents in the format of

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f8a61df2f74ae5aed652d2e"
    },
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "adx": [],
    "sma": [],
    "time": [],
    "minusdmi": [],
    "plusdmi": []
}
```

How do I return documents where the last element of the "plusdmi" array is greater than the last element of the "minusdmi" array.

I've tried

```
{$expr:{$gt: ["plusdmi.14", "minusdmi.14"]}}
```

But that seems to return every document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework to achieve your use case.

Use operator [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) that returns the element at the specified array index.
Last element can be accessed using -1 as array index

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$plusdmi",
              -1
            ]
          },
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$minusdmi",
              -1
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KIMuvfEKkJP)